# Geocoder getFromLocationName() not working, returning 0 values

Tags: android, location, android-location, geocoder

I want to get a list of the 5 adresses more similar to the string passed, but something is not working.

For example, if I write "avenida" there are thousands of "avenida" streets in spain, but the method getFromLocationName returns 0.

```
private void getAddressInfo(Context context, String locationName){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        try {
        List<Address> a = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
            String city = a.get(0).getLocality();
            String country = a.get(0).getCountryName();
            String address = a.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
            addressList.add(address+", "+city+", "+country);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: Perhaps that is too general. If you provide something more specific, do you get results?

Comment: @CommonsWare nope, no results, or results with non sense, for example i remember to see a result once, but non related, from other country. Something is really bad

Comment: I haven't used `Geocoder` in a few months. It's backed by some Google servers; perhaps something is screwed up there.

Comment: @CommonsWare i don't think so, i'm with this problem since I started it one week ago

Answer (score 0):

I just confirmed this in code; the way it works is you give it a valid place name, like an address.  It does not need a city.  then it should give you a list of as many as it finds. not as useful as expected. A street or business name does not seem to work. :-(

if i do 2000 east main without a city i get a hit

if i do east main i get 0

[I am going to use this instead](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos)

Comment: and what can I do with that?

Comment: I have not implemented it yet but you tell it what fields to search for and it starts a task that returns a list of matches.  So if I add a field for a part of an address like street, then add the query in the builder it returns matches.  the project itself is just a demo of the places api.

Comment: how it works? I started the demo project and i can see three buttons but they don't do anything when you press them

Comment: if you post another question about the current place demo i will answer with how I got it going

Comment: as i can understand, this needs to enable billing, so it's a pay per use thing. Or not?

Comment: Yes and if you restrict the key to android you need to sign the app

Comment: if you need to pay for using it then it's not an option for me

Comment: It is free but in order to use it you have to link a billing account to it

Comment: it's free? then for what is need the billing account?